# CSP with javascript in "document.location"

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

Our application is being updated to comply with new CSP (Content Security Policy) rules.

E.g. Inline event handlers are replaced with `addEventListener()`, and inline styles replaced with CSS.

However, in some instances document location is set to a javascript expression, like so...

```
document.location = 'javascript:someFunction()';
```

...which causes the following error...

```
"Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline'
```

**My question:** What is an equivalent way of re-writing this so that it complies with CSP rules?

Comment: just `document.location = someFunction();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is blocked by [`unsafe-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_inline_script). Please consider either:

1. If `someFunction()` returns an valid URI, you can write `document.location = someFunction();` as @ControlAltDel mentions.
2. If it does not, you can just call `someFunction()`.